# Login com facebook

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, login

Tenho uma duvida em relação ao login através de Facebook.

Eu tenho uma base dados com uma tabela utilizadores e tenho um sistema de registo e login normal, mas queria implementar o sistema de login através do Facebook.

Como faço para que o sistema saiba quando tem de registar ou fazer login? Por exemplo, eu entro com o Facebook da primeira vez e o site tem de criar um espaço na base de dados para mim mas da segunda vez ele deveria acessar os meus dados já registados, como faço isso?

Answer (score 2):

Primeiramente você precisa cadastrar sua aplicação no facebook:
https://developers.facebook.com/

Apos isso você terá uma api-key e api-secret que identificam seu aplicativo no facebook.

Feito isso você pode usar uma bilioteca para implementar o OAuth ou fazer na mão (http://oauth.net/2/)

Eu estou estudando a seguinte biblioteca Java para fazer login e publicar no face:

> https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java

Quando o usuário faz login pela primeira vez ele autoriza o acesso, e após isso toda vez que fizer o acesso não será mais pedido a autorização. Isso quer dizer, você vai gravar o token de autorização na sua base de dados para não precisar mais pedir nos próximos acessos.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.